# Excel generates multiple digits

Tags: excel

When extracting a file from SAP, some numbers are generated with multiple digits on the excel file which is not the way they appear in SAP. For example, the first one is just 20 and appears as a large number

[image]

Could this be an issue with Excel default number format (though I haven't changed anything) ?

This is the format when I click on the cell

[image]

As the excel file is automatically generated, I would like for the format to be OK upon opening, without having to manually change it

Can I achieve that on excel?

Edit: Here are my computer default data formats

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the output conditions?

Comment: Excel doesn't generate extra digits and I'm pretty sure France doesn't use `,` for both the decimal and thousand separators. Is your computer misconfigured? What kind of files does SAP generate? CSV text files or `xlsx` Excel files?

Comment: @SolarMike What output conditions are you referring to? SAP ones? if it's the case, the SAP technical team is insisting it's not coming from their end

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it used to work perfectly and I don't recall any computer configurations changes - is there a default option we can change ? SAP generates an xlsx

Comment: So check the output file BEFORE you open it in excel - use a text editor, there are some that will read the file ignoring any formatting etc I used to use "programmers file EDitor' but there are equivalents.

Comment: @SolarMike I just opened it with a text editor and I have the correct values

Comment: Are you sure it is an `.xlsx` file? An `.xlsx` file is a zipped file and can't be open with an ordinary text editor. It has to be unzipped and then each file opened individually.

Comment: @notarobot if you opened the `xlsx` file with a text editor, it's most definitely *NOT* an `xlsx` file, but a text file with a fake extension. Excel will try to *import* it as a CSV file using the user locale's defaults for list, decimal and thousand separators. In Europe, the list separator is `;`. If the file contains `20,0,0;Whatever`, then Excel will import it as two text fields.

Comment: You can control which separators are used by using the `Data` menu instead of double-clicking on the file.

Comment: I wasn't very clear, I did not open the actual xlsx file with a text editor, but on SAP, they give us multiple options to open the file and I chose "txt" instead of "generate an excel file". i don't know if that changes anything

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'll check this, I also added the actual computer formats in my post if you don't mind taking a look

Comment: Just because the `.txt` file has the correct values does not necessarily mean that the `.xlsx` file has the correct values. To check the `.xlsx` file you would need to unzip it, then check the appropriate file within the zipped structure. Also, your default formats in your picture are not correct. You might try **deleting the formats** that are showing commas for both the digit and decimal separators. There is no locale that would be using that.

Comment: Do you think there may be a conflict with your settings of using a comma for decimal AND a comma for leading zeroes?

Comment: @SolarMike i'm not sure. and that's the thing, I never picked the leading zeroes comma setting. I don't know where it's coming from and I want to disable it but i dont know how

Comment: Looks like it is a dropdown box - but they are YOUR settings... As in: "*Here are my computer default data formats*"

Comment: You might need to check the transaction code you are applying in `SAP` dont think its a problem with `Excel` ? Could you consult with your `IT` desk once.

Comment: ***Delete those formats with the double commas*** from your custom list.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I tried deleting them but it doesn't work :( excel restarts each time and the formats are still there

Comment: Is the format present whenever you open Excel on your computer- even with just a blank document? And if you remove the format, do your numbers display with expected values? This will give us a hint as to whether the problem is with your workbook or the file being generated by SAP

Comment: @RonRosenfeld yes, the format is present even with a blank document and i can't delete it from the list. if i chose the standard format, the correct values do appear. what does this mean ?

Comment: Something has changed to make that format permanent on your computer. Some of the possibilities have to do with a personal.xlsx file; a style that is including that format (maybe the "normal" style or whatever is being applied when you open the SAP derived xlsx file; or your normal template *.dotm. You can do an internet search for how to locate and correct these kinds of errors.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks I'll look into that. Is it likely that it was caused by an Excel update ? I can't think of anything else that might've changed

Comment: Unlikely in my opinion or many of the people would have been affected.